# Spells / methods to restore magical aging

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

I ran a custom encounter where my party had to use their life force (age) to restore the life and age to two Royal NPCs (drained by an evil magical entity as it can do this to creatures of royal blood). To restore the life force back to the two NPCs I allowed the condition that if they willingly give their life force the magical entity can medium the transfer at a much higher cost (4-8 years of their life = 1 of the Royals). Luckily they had a gnome who is now 210 years older.

After this my party is going to try to find ways to restore themselves to their previous age and I am preventing them from using the same method used before (as the evil entity sees no benefit in restoring them). This now has become a side quest for the party. I have not been able to find any high level spells or other methods of restoring lost age in the handbooks, and I am looking some ideas on how I might later give them a chance to restore them. I can create another custom encounter around this, but I don't want to make this easy for them.

Comment: Hi! I've edited your question for some minor grammatical fixin's and tried to clarify a few things a tiny bit better. You can rewind the edit if you feel like I took something out, or you can edit it further if you'd like.  I also kind of want to ask, so that we can answer things better or make your question easier for us to read, but what _exactly_ do you want to know?

Comment: I'm kind of stuck on an interesting way to progress this, i feel its a good side quest to keep the party searching for answers but at the moment i don't have the answers for them. Just looking for some ideas / existing lore in previous editions that i could build upon to give the players something to aim towards.

Comment: Sorry, Gus, I voted to close your question. Open-ended idea-generation is not a good fit for this site's Q&A format. You may want to try a forum, [here's a few we recommend](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23064). Or, when you have enough reputation, you can join us at [chat].

Comment: I think, instead of fishing for ideas as that is not what this site is for, you could frame the question to be asking about whatever is already present in the rules fitting certain requirements. **Short Version** there needs to be some definitive answer or finite set of answers that we can vote on. If you need help with that, you can check out the [tour] or the [help].

Comment: Comments are for clarifying content of a question, please don't answer in them. @Gus, I just +1'ed your question so you can get enough rep to join us in [chat] if you want to discuss with the community about this. Pop on by!